# can not create PeerAdmin Card when deploying hyperledger fabric and the error is below

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Using composer-cli at v0.20.0

```
Successfully created business network card file to 
    Output file: /tmp/PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card

Command succeeded

+ /home/fabric/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/composer card import --file /tmp/PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card
./createPeerAdminCard.sh: line 161: 17380 Bus error               "${HL_COMPOSER_CLI}" card import --file /tmp/PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card
+ set +x
There are no Business Network Cards available.

Command succeeded
```

Comment: when i run ./createPeerAdminCard.sh script to generate PeerAdmin Card ,it cause   bus error

Comment: Please add the code that causes the error to your question :-) (createPeerAdminCard.sh, arround line 161) You can edit your question by pressing "edit" on the bottom left of your question.

Comment: @唐大哥 `./createPeerAdminCard.sh` is a Composer Dev (toolset) script. If you follow the instructions (Controlling your Dev environment") here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html and follow the instructions it points out - then you should be good.